# Right way to delete a row in ado.net entity data model

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net-entity-data-model

I need to delete a row using ado.net entity data model. Already googling about this, but i still can't find out how to do it right.

Here's my code:

```
else if (mode == 3)
            {
                LaundryEntities1 db = new LaundryEntities1();
                var query = (from user in db.Users
                             where user.UserID == textBoxID.Text
                             select user).First();
                db.DeleteObject(query);
                db.SaveChanges();
                reload();
                MessageBox.Show("Succesfully delete a user");
                clear();
            }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what isn't working here?

Comment: delete function is not working, every time I use it, nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a public class named Session

```
public class session
    {
        public static DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
        public static User user = null;
    }
```

and changed my code into

```
Users user = (from x in session.db.Users
              where x.UserID == textBoxID.Text
              select x).FirstOrDefault();
session.db.Users.DeleteObject(user);
session.db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
LaundryEntities1 db = new LaundryEntities1();
            var query = (from user in db.Users
                         where user.UserID == textBoxID.Text
                         select user).First();

            db.Entry(employer).State = EntityState.Deleted

            if(db.SaveChanges())
              MessageBox.Show("Succesfully delete a user");
```

Comment: thanks, I'm using visual studio 2010 btw, but there is no db.Entry am I missing something?

Comment: do you use "System.Linq;" ?

Comment: Or maybe,you should update or install nuget your packages

Comment: already have System.Linq, i already solve my own problem but i will try to use your option too. Thanks